# How can I view title text for a web image (xkcd.com) on an Android based browser?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, browser

How can I see the title <del>alt</del> text for website images on an HTC Desire?

I'm currently using the Dolphin HD browser but I can't see a way of getting the alt text.

Comment: Be an activist and upvote the [defect here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5836)! Though that's a longer term answer. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good question. I don't see an obvious way to do that to solve your problem on all websites. However, there just so happens to be a few xkcd viewer apps. I use [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bytten.xkcdviewer&hl=en) which has a menu > hover text option.

**EDIT:**
This seems like a reasonable thing to try for link hover text, but it does not work for me on the default HTC Incredible browser:

> 1. Tap any white empty space near to the link you want to hover over.
> 2. Now move your trackball up/down until it selects the link. Don’t click it.
> 3. There! The tooltip now appears. Simple solution. :)

I saw this suggested [here](http://nitendra.com/blog/2010/05/mouseover-hover-tootltipin-android-browser/).

Comment: Cheers, that's helpful but unfortunately the hover suggestion doesn't work in the case of xkcd.com - maybe because the images aren't links?  The app is a reasonable workaround for now though.

Comment: Not every Android phone has a trackball, either.

Comment: App no longer available.

Answer (score 43):

The right answer is to just go to https://m.xkcd.com. There is a link on there to show or hide the alt text.

Comment: Works perfectly for xkcd, but not for other sites/situations.

Answer (score 2):

I created a bookmarklet for this:

```
javascript:(function(){var D=document,i,f,j,e;for(i=0;f=D.images[i];++i)if(f.title!=""){var x=D.createElement("div"),s=x.style;s.color="Black ";s.background="yellow ";x.innerHTML=f.title;f.parentNode.insertBefore(x,f.nextSibling);}})();
```

This displays any TITLE texts as text with yellow background.

Answer (score 0):

Download XKCD viewer app in the android market. You can then tap on the comic to bring up the hover text.